# Service Portal Widget form Returns "Record not Found"

Tags: angularjs, servicenow

I created new widget by cloning existing form widget in Service Portal (ServiceNow). Modified sys_id and table name in the URL (https://dev32223.service-now.com/aaportal/?id=departments&table=x_34334_aaaa_incident&sys_id=ee384830db2e32001cf8dec0cf9619de). Created new page with the widget and the resulting web page shows 'Record Not Found'

HTML:

```
<div ng-if="!data.isValid && !data.emptyStateTemplate" class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body wrapper-lg text-center">
    ${Record not found}
  </div>
</div>

<div ng-if="!data.isValid && data.emptyStateTemplate" class="panel-shift">
  <div class="empty-state-wrapper panel panel-default" ng-include="data.emptyStateTemplate"></div>
</div>

<div ng-if="data.isValid" class="panel-shift">
  <div class="" ng-if="!data.f._view.length && data.hideRelatedLists && data.emptyStateTemplate">
    <div class="empty-state-wrapper panel panel-default" ng-include="data.emptyStateTemplate"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="" ng-if="!data.f._view.length && data.hideRelatedLists && !data.emptyStateTemplate">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading"><span class="panel-title">{{data.f.title}}</span> <span ng-if="options.showFormView == 'true' && data.f.view != ''">[{{data.f.view_title}} view]</span></div>
      <div class="panel-body wrapper-lg text-center">
        ${No elements to display}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default" ng-if="data.f._view.length || !data.hideRelatedLists" >
    <div class="panel-heading" ng-if="data.f.title.length" sp-context-menu="getUIActionContextMenu(event)">
        <span class="dropdown m-r-xs" ng-if="(data.isAdmin || getUIActions('context').length > 0) && options.omitHeaderOptions != 'true'">
            <span class="dropdown-toggle glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" style="line-height: 1.4em" id="adminMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"></span>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="adminMenu">
              <li ng-if="::data.isAdmin"><a href="/{{data.f.table}}.do?sys_id={{data.f.sys_id}}" target="_blank">${Open in platform}</a></li>
              <li ng-if="::data.isAdmin" class="dropdown-header">${Configure}</li>
              <li ng-if="::data.isAdmin"><a href="/slushbucket.do?sysparm_referring_url={{adminMenu.encodedPageUrl}}&sysparm_list={{data.f._sections[0].id}}&sysparm_form=section&sysparm_view={{data.f.view}}" target="_blank">${Form Layout}</a></li>
              <li ng-if="::data.isAdmin"><a href="/slushbucket.do?sysparm_referring_url={{adminMenu.encodedPageUrl}}&sysparm_list={{data.f.table}}&sysparm_form=related_list&sysparm_view={{data.f.view}}" target="_blank">${Related Lists}</a></li>
              <li ng-if="::data.isAdmin"><a href="?id=lf&table=sys_ui_policy&filter=table%3D{{data.f.table}}%5EORtableIN{{data.tableHierarchy}}%5Eactive%3Dtrue%5Eui_type%3D1%5EORui_type%3D10" ng-click="openRelatedList($event, {id:'lf', table: 'sys_ui_policy', filter: 'table%3D{{data.f.table}}%5EORtableIN{{data.f.table}},sys_metadata%5Eactive%3Dtrue%5Eui_type%3D1%5EORui_type%3D10'})">${UI Policies} <span class="badge pull-right" ng-if="f.policy.length">{{f.policy.length}}</span></a></li>
              <li ng-if="::data.isAdmin"><a href="?id=lf&table=sys_script_client&filter=table%3D{{data.f.table}}%5EORtableIN{{data.tableHierarchy}}%5Eactive%3Dtrue%5Eui_type%3D1%5EORui_type%3D10" ng-click="openRelatedList($event, {id: 'lf', table: 'sys_script_client', filter: 'table%3D{{data.f.table}}%5EORtableIN{{data.f.table}},sys_metadata%5Eactive%3Dtrue%5Eui_type%3D1%5EORui_type%3D10'})">${Client Scripts} <span class="badge pull-right" ng-if="adminMenu.getClientScriptCount()">{{adminMenu.getClientScriptCount()}}</span></a></li>
              <li ng-if="getUIActions('context').length > 0 &&  data.isAdmin" role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li ng-repeat="action in getUIActions('context')"><a href="" ng-click="triggerUIAction(action)">{{action.name}}</a></li>
              <li ng-if="::data.isAdmin || getUIActions('context').length > 0" role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a target="_new" href="/{{data.f.table}}.do?PDF&sys_id={{data.sys_id}}&sysparm_view={{data.f.view}}">${Export to PDF}</a></li>
              <li><a target="_new" href="/{{data.f.table}}.do?PDF&landscape=true&sys_id={{data.sys_id}}&sysparm_view={{data.f.view}}">${Export to PDF (landscape)}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </span>
      <span class="panel-title">{{data.f.title}}</span> <span ng-if="options.showFormView == 'true' && data.f.view != ''">[{{data.f.view_title}} view]</span>
      <div ng-if="attachmentHandler && data.canAttach" title="{{::data.addAttachmentMsg}}" class="pull-right attachment-button">
        <sp-attachment-button></sp-attachment-button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <!-- performance debug -->
      <div ng-if="data.show_sql">
        <div class="comment">
          <span ng-if="data.f._perf.sql_count">${SQL Statements {{data.f._perf.sql_count}}}, </span>
          <span>${Time {{data.f._perf.time}}}</span>
        </div>
        <div ng-repeat="s in data.f._perf.sql" class="{{s.type}}">
          {{s.statement}}
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- attachments -->
      <sp-attachment-manager table="data.table" sys-id="data.f._attachmentGUID" omit-edit="!data.canAttach"></sp-attachment-manager>
      <!-- form -->
      <div>
        <sp-model form_model="data.f" mandatory="mandatory"></sp-model>
      </div>
      <!-- UI Action Links -->
      <div ng-if="getUIActions('link').length > 0">
        <label style="margin: 0;">${Related Links}</label>
        <div ng-repeat="action in getUIActions('link')">
          <a href ng-click="triggerUIAction(action)">{{action.name}}</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- related lists -->
      <div ng-if="!data.hideRelatedLists">
        <label style="margin: 0">${Related Lists}</label>
        <div style="margin-bottom: 7px; padding-bottom: 7px; border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;">
          <span ng-repeat="rl in data.f._related_lists" ng-if="rl.visible">
            <a ng-if="rl.type != 'REL'" href="?id=lf&table={{rl.table}}&filter={{rl.field}}%3D{{data.f.sys_id}}&view={{data.f.view}}" ng-click="openRelatedList($event, {id: 'lf', table: '{{rl.table}}', filter: '{{rl.field}}%3D{{data.f.sys_id}}'})">{{rl.plural}}
              <span class="label label-as-badge label-primary" ng-if="rl.count">{{rl.count}}</span>
            </a>
            <a ng-if="rl.type == 'REL'" href="?id=lf&table={{rl.table}}&relationship_id={{rl.relationship_id}}&apply_to={{rl.apply_to}}&apply_to_sys_id={{rl.apply_to_sys_id}}&view={{data.f.view}}" ng-click="openRelatedList($event, {id: 'lf', table: '{{rl.table}}', apply_to: '{{rl.apply_to}}', apply_to_sys_id: '{{rl.apply_to_sys_id}}', relationship_id: '{{rl.relationship_id}}'})">{{rl.label}}
              <span class="label label-as-badge label-primary" ng-if="rl.count">{{rl.count}}</span>
            </a>
            <span ng-if="!$last" style="padding-left: .5em; padding-right: .5em;"> | </span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-footer">
      <button ng-mousedown="triggerUIAction(action)" ng-repeat="action in getUIActions('button')" class="btn btn-default action-btn">{{action.name}}</button>
      <span>{{status}}</span>
      <button ng-if="getPrimaryAction()" type="submit" ng-mousedown="triggerUIAction(getPrimaryAction())" class="btn btn-primary action-btn pull-right">${Save} <span ng-if="saveButtonSuffix">(${{{saveButtonSuffix}}})</span></button>
      <div style="clear: both;"></div>
      <div ng-if="mandatory.length" class="alert alert-info" style="margin-top: .5em">
        <span ng-if="mandatory.length > 0">${Required information} </span>
        <span ng-repeat="f in mandatory" class="label label-danger" style="margin-right: .5em; display: inline-block;">{{f.label}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Client Script:

```
function ($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, spUtil, $location, $window, nowAttachmentHandler) {
    $scope.mandatory = [];
    $scope.data.show_sql = false;
    $scope.saveButtonSuffix = spUtil.getAccelerator('s');
    $scope.adminMenu = {
        encodedPageUrl: encodeURIComponent($location.url()),
        getClientScriptCount: function() {
            var count = 0;
            if ($scope.data.f.client_script) {
                count += $scope.data.f.client_script.onChange.length;
                count += $scope.data.f.client_script.onLoad.length;
                count += $scope.data.f.client_script.onSubmit.length;
            }
            return count;
        }
    };

    $scope.getUIActions = function(type) {
        if ($scope.data.disableUIActions)
            return [];
        if (type) {
            return $scope.data.f._ui_actions.filter(function(action) {
                //We handle the primary action button separately.
                return !action.primary && action['is_' + type];
            });
        } else {
            return $scope.data.f._ui_actions;
        }
    }

    $scope.getPrimaryAction = function() {
        var primaryActions = $scope.data.f._ui_actions.filter(function(action) {
            return action.primary;
        });
        return (primaryActions.length) ? primaryActions[0] : null;
    }

    $scope.getUIActionContextMenu = function(event) {
        var menu = [];
        if (event.ctrlKey)
            return menu;

        var contextActions = $scope.getUIActions('context');
        contextActions.forEach(function(action) {
            menu.push([action.name, function() {
                $scope.triggerUIAction(action);
            }]);
        });

        if (contextActions.length > 0)
            menu.push(null);
        menu.push([$scope.data.exportPDFMsg, function() {exportPDF("");}]);
        menu.push([$scope.data.exportPDFLandMsg, function() {exportPDF('true');}]);

        return menu;
    }

    function exportPDF(landscape) {
        $window.open("/" + $scope.data.f.table + ".do?PDF&landscape=" + landscape + "&sys_id=" + $scope.data.sys_id + "&sysparm_view=" + $scope.data.f.view);
    }

    //trigger the primary UI Action on save (if there is one)
    var deregister = $scope.$on('$sp.save', function() {
        var primaryAction = $scope.getPrimaryAction();
        if (primaryAction)
            $scope.triggerUIAction(primaryAction);
    });
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {deregister()});

    $scope.triggerUIAction = function(action) {
        if ($scope.data.disableUIActions)
            return;

        if (g_form) {
            $timeout(function() {
                g_form.submit(action.action_name || action.sys_id);
            });
        }
    }

    $scope.$on("spModel.uiActionComplete", function(evt, response) {
        var sysID = (response.isInsert) ? response.sys_id : $scope.data.sys_id;
        loadForm($scope.data.table, sysID).then(constructResponseHandler(response));
    });

    function constructResponseHandler(response) {
        return function() {
            var message;
            var eventName = "sp.form.record.updated";
            if (response.isInsert) {
                message = $scope.data.recordAddedMsg;
                var search = $location.search();
                search.sys_id = response.sys_id;
                search.spa = 1;
                $location.search(search).replace();
            } else
                message = $scope.data.updatedMsg;

            $scope.data.hideRelatedLists = hideRelatedLists();
            $scope.$emit(eventName, $scope.data.f._fields);
            $rootScope.$broadcast(eventName, $scope.data.f._fields);
            $scope.status = message;
            spUtil.addTrivialMessage(message);
            $timeout(clearStatus, 2000);
        }
    }

    var ctrl = this;
    // switch forms
    var unregister = $scope.$on('$sp.list.click', onListClick);
    $scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
        unregister();
    })

    function onListClick(evt,arg) {
        loadForm(arg.table, arg.sys_id);
    }

    function loadForm(table, sys_id){
        var f = {};
        //$scope.data.table = f.table = 'x_19668_halo_incident';
        //$scope.data.sys_id = f.sys_id ='ee384830db2e32001cf8dec0cf9619de';
        $scope.data.table = f.table = table;
      $scope.data.sys_id = f.sys_id = sys_id;
        f.view = $scope.data.view;
        return $scope.server.update().then(setupAttachmentHandler);
    }

    function openRelatedList(e, queryString){
        // todo: Open this in a modal
        $location.search(queryString);
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    $scope.$on('spModel.fields.rendered', function() {
        if (ctrl.panels)
            ctrl.panels.removeClass('shift-out').addClass('shift-in');
    });

    var g_form;
    $scope.$on('spModel.gForm.initialized', function(e, gFormInstance) {
        if (gFormInstance.getTableName() == $scope.data.f.table)
            g_form = gFormInstance;
    });

    // Show or hide related lists
    $scope.$watch('data.f._related_lists', function(){
        $scope.data.hideRelatedLists = hideRelatedLists();
    }, true);

    function hideRelatedLists() {
        if (!$scope.data.f._related_lists)
            return true;

        if ($scope.options.hideRelatedLists == true)
            return true;

        if ($scope.data.sys_id == '-1')
            return true;

        // If all related lists are visible=false then hide
        if ($scope.data.f._related_lists.length > 0) {
            for (var i in $scope.data.f._related_lists) {
                var list = $scope.data.f._related_lists[i];
                if (list.visible) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    function clearStatus() {
        $scope.status = "";
    }

    function setupAttachmentHandler(){
        $scope.attachmentHandler = new nowAttachmentHandler(appendSuccess, appendError);

        $timeout(function() {
            var sizeLimit = 1024 * 1024 * 24; // 24MB
            $scope.attachmentHandler.setParams($scope.data.table, $scope.data.f._attachmentGUID, sizeLimit);
        });

        $scope.$on('dialog.upload_too_large.show', function(e){
            console.log($scope.data.largeAttachmentMsg);
            spUtil.addErrorMessage($scope.data.largeAttachmentMsg);
        });
    }
    setupAttachmentHandler();

    function appendSuccess() {
        spUtil.addTrivialMessage($scope.data.attachmentUploadSuccessMsg);
        $scope.$broadcast("sp.attachments.update", $scope.data.f._attachmentGUID);
    }

    function appendError(error) {
        $scope.errorMessages.push(error);
    }
}
```

Server Script:

```
// form functionality - URL parameter driven
(function($sp, input, data, options, gs) 
{
  /* "use strict"; -linter issues */
  // populate the 'data' variable   
    data.attachmentUploadSuccessMsg = gs.getMessage("Attachment upload was successful");
    data.recordAddedMsg = gs.getMessage("Record Added");
    data.updatedMsg = gs.getMessage("updated_uppercase");
    data.exportPDFMsg = gs.getMessage("Export to PDF");
    data.exportPDFLandMsg = gs.getMessage("Export to PDF (landscape)");
    data.addAttachmentMsg = gs.getMessage("Add an attachment");
    data.largeAttachmentMsg = gs.getMessage("Attached files must be smaller than {0} - please try again", "24MB");

    data.isAdmin = true;
    data.emptyStateTemplate = options.empty_state_template;
    data.disableUIActions = options.disableUIActions || false;
    data.hideRelatedLists = options.hideRelatedLists || false;

    if (input) {
        data.table = input.table;
        data.sys_id = input.sys_id;
        data.view = input.view;
        var result = {};
        if (input._fields)
            result = $sp.saveRecord(input.table, input.sys_id, input._fields);

        if (input.sys_id == '-1'){
            data.sys_id = result.sys_id;
            data.isNewRecord = true;
        }
    } else {
        data.table = $sp.getParameter("t") || $sp.getParameter("table") || $sp.getParameter("sl_table") || options.table;
        data.sys_id = $sp.getParameter("sys_id") || $sp.getParameter("sl_sys_id") || options.sys_id;
        data.view = $sp.getParameter("v") || $sp.getParameter("view") || options.view; // no default
    }

    data.query = $sp.getParameter("query") || options.query;
    data.f = {};
    if (!data.table)
        return;

    //if (!GlideTableDescriptor.isValid(data.table))
        //return;

    if (!data.sys_id)
        return;
    gs.info("data.table, data.sys_id 3:");
    var rec = $sp.getRecord(data.table, data.sys_id);       gs.info("data.table, data.sys_id 31:");
    data.isValid = rec.isValid() || data.sys_id == "-1";    gs.info("data.table, data.sys_id 32:");
    gs.info("data.table, data.sys_id 4:");
    if (!data.isValid)
        return;
  gs.info("data.table, data.sys_id  :"+data.table+ data.sys_id);
    data.table = rec.getRecordClassName();
    data.tableHierarchy = GlideDBObjectManager.getTables(data.table).toArray().join();
    data.canWrite = rec.canWrite();
    data.canAttach = data.canWrite && gs.hasRole(gs.getProperty('glide.attachment.role')) && !GlideTableDescriptor.get(data.table).getED().getBooleanAttribute("no_attachment");
    data.f = $sp.getForm(data.table, data.sys_id, data.query, data.view);

    // Activity formatter is hardcoded to set specific options
    for (var f in data.f._formatters) {
        var fm = data.f._formatters[f];
        if (fm.formatter == "activity.xml") {
            fm.hardcoded = true;
            fm.widgetInstance = $sp.getWidget('widget-ticket-conversation',
                                                                {table: data.table,
                                                                 sys_id: data.sys_id,
                                                                 includeExtended: true,
                                                                 title: "${Activity}",
                                                                 placeholder: "${Add a comment}",
                                                                 btnLabel: "${Post}"});
        } else
            fm.widgetInstance = $sp.getWidget(fm.widget, data);
    }
})($sp, input, data, options, gs);
```

Comment: Does it print all log messages?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the control is not passing the line  `var rec = $sp.getRecord(data.table, data.sys_id);` I can not figure out the issue, but I have an alternate solution. You can use iframes (shown below) to show form or list of records.
[image: Widget with iFrame]

Mark it as answer if this answers your question.

Comment: Let me try this